# How to get Microsoft Edge (and other Windows applications) to close cleanly?

Tags: python, winapi

I'm writing some JS benchmarking automation in Python and need to fire up and stop Microsoft Edge. I've managed to get Edge going just fine with `subprocess.Popen()` but for the life of me I can't get it to stop cleanly--nor any other Windows application, for that matter.

No matter what signal I send to MicrosoftEdge.exe or other apps, one of two things happen: nothing, or the application gets force-killed. I've tried `WM_CLOSE`, `CTRL_C_EVENT`, `SIGINT`, and so on. The basic question is what signal do I send that equates the user clicking the "close" button? (I'm aware that Edge is a UWP app, by the way.)

This is where it gets even more interesting. I tried to work around the problem by calling `taskkill /im instead`. It works as expected with almost every Windows application (for example, if there's Wordpad open with some text, you get a save prompt), but it does absolutely nothing to Edge. I'm about to start tearing my hair out :)

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'd rather keep this simple, but I might have to resort to using something like Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SendMessage (or PostMessage) (hEdgeTopLevelWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
```

That should make Edge think that the user has clicked the Close button.  But over to you, @IInspectable.

But how are you getting hold of `hEdgeTopLevelWnd`?  You need to make sure you get the right one - there are a few, in the (minimal) window hierarchy used by UWP apps.